# http request takes time if i use domain name instead of ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, dns, get

I am sending an HTTP GET request in postman.

the first request is using IP address i.e.

```
get 52.66.166.14
```

which takes around 70ms to complete.

The second request is using domain name, i.e.

```
get dev.iotrek.in
```

which takes around 450ms to complete.

What is the reason fo this to occur? this delay that I am getting in apis.

My server is running nginx-passenger.
My backend is ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That difference probably amounts to your latency to the DNS server.

For example here is a request with my ISP DNS:

```
$ curl --silent --output /dev/null example.com -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}
0.142:0.252:0.252
```

Here is a request with a DNS from another continent:

```
$ curl --silent --output /dev/null example.com -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}
0.414:0.525:0.525
```

Notice the time_connect is quite different. Consider using a DNS, that is geographically more suitable for you.